# Getting null values when pivoting the data based on the join condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one requirement where I have to join two tables based on the id. I have done the fiddle as well for this but there is one column E_CLUBBED_E which is populating as null but ideally, it should match the column `ref_ans_value` of `ques_ans` table and give the output but I am getting null.

Reason: I am getting null because `ref_ans_id` is null for `ref_ques_id` and I am joining

```
join ans_ref ar
on ar.ref_ans_id = qa.ref_ans_id
```

so this might be the reason of getting null values.

But this is the ideal scenario where for `ref_ques_id` 23 `ref_ans_id` will be null only and based on this I have to populate `ref_ans_value` of `ques_ans` table.

```
CREATE TABLE details_1 (
    e_id    NUMBER(10),
    e_name  VARCHAR2(30),
    CONSTRAINT pk_details_1_e_id PRIMARY KEY ( e_id )
);

insert into details_1 values(11,'A');

CREATE TABLE ques_ref (
    ques_id     NUMBER(10),
    code        VARCHAR2(50),
    code_label  VARCHAR2(100),
    constraint pk_ques_ref primary key(ques_id)
);

insert into ques_ref values(3,'changes_exist','Any known changes');
insert into ques_ref values(2,'E_Clubbed','E_id clubbed with other');
insert into ques_ref values(4,'E_impacted','E impacted by other');
insert into ques_ref values(23,'E_Clubbed_with_other','E clubbed with other E');


CREATE TABLE ques_ans (
    ques_ans_id  NUMBER(10),
    ref_ques_id  NUMBER(10),
    ref_ans_id   NUMBER(10),
    ref_ans_value VARCHAR2(100),
    e_id         NUMBER(10),
    CONSTRAINT pk_ques_ans PRIMARY KEY ( ques_ans_id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_ques_ans FOREIGN KEY ( e_id )
        REFERENCES details_1 ( e_id ),
        constraint fk_ques_and_ques_id foreign key(ref_ques_id)
        references ques_ref (ques_id)
);

insert into ques_ans values(1,3,1,null,11);
insert into ques_ans values(2,2,2,null,11);
insert into ques_ans values(3,4,1,null,11);
insert into ques_ans values(4,23,null,1234,11);



CREATE TABLE ans_ref (
    ref_ans_id  NUMBER(10),
    code        VARCHAR2(10),
    code_value  VARCHAR2(30)
);

insert into ans_ref values(1,'R_Yes','Yes');
insert into ans_ref values(2,'R_No','No');
```

Fiddle : [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a5190f7dd57416772bf8e25672c090fb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your last inner join to left join of table ans_ref -

```
select  d.e_id,
        max(case qa.ref_ques_id when 3 then ar.code_value end) changes_exist,
        max(case qa.ref_ques_id when 2 then ar.code_value end) E_Clubbed,
        max(case qa.ref_ques_id when 4 then ar.code_value end) E_impacted,
        max(case qa.ref_ques_id when 23 then qa.ref_ans_value end) E_CLUBBED_E
  from      details_1 d
        join
            ques_ans qa
          on d.e_id = qa.e_id
        left join ans_ref ar
          on ar.ref_ans_id = qa.ref_ans_id
 group by d.e_id
```

[Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4a5ead9a7e56ef60601a68f966bcab52)

Comment: @Vicky, Actually its not. You have not included the query and sample data in the question. Thats why it was downvoted.

Comment: I had posted the fiddle that's why I didn't post the sample data in the question rather posted the fiddle link

Comment: Normally people prefer to read the question instead of going to fiddle link.

Comment: Thanks again but as your comment says that I had posted the sample data because there was some misunderstanding from my side that if I am pasting the fiddle link then sample data itself is provided in fiddle so I did post the link. But going forward I will take care of this. I am pasting the sample data in the original question so that I will get up vote for this question. Please do the needful.